# Binding em TextBox com DataGrid (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox, datagrid

Eu tenho um TextBox onde recebe o id do cliente e também tenho um DataGrid onde ele tem umas informações pessoais. Bom até ai tudo bem, o que eu não estou conseguindo é ligar os dois da seguinte forma:

Quando eu alterar o valor do TextBox (id do cliente) mudando de foco, ele teria que alterar os dados do DataGrid de acordo com o cliente selecionado na TextBox

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=dataGridTelefones, 
                Path=SelectedItem.id_empresa,
                NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}" 
         Name="textCodigo" />

<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
          Margin="12,12,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"
          ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGridTelefones" Height="100"
          Canvas.Left="113" Canvas.Top="539"
          Width="938" FontWeight="Normal" GridLinesVisibility="All"
          IsReadOnly="True" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
          <DataGrid.Columns>
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=prefixo}"
                                  Header="Prefixo" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=telefone}"
                                  Header="Telefone" />
              <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=obs}"
                                  Header="Observações" />
          </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar?